# External screen turns off after macOS boots - Mac Mini

Tags: macos, mac, mac-mini

When I plug in the screen and I turn on the Mac Mini, I see the Apple logo and the OS loading. After macOS boots the external screen goes black.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with EV3237 Monitor. Also, when I was lucky that the Mac Mini somehow started to send a signal, then the screen would go black randomly for a few seconds while I was working on it.

I tried the PRAM and SMC thing - no difference. I tried HDMI - no difference. On the other hand, I had no issue on a LG 4k 27" Monitor.

Finally I found a way to stop this: On the EV3237, I turned off the power saving feature. Now, my Monitor will only be off when I turn it off. On the other hand, I have a stable screen now. Somehow the signal from the Mac Mini seems to initiate a power saving on some monitors I guess.

So try to turn off power saving on your monitor.

Comment: Same behaviour confirmed on an ASUS VS248HR external monitor with Mac Mini. Turning off "ECO Mode" resolved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Since Mojave 10.14.6 the issue seems to be gone. So probably an OS bug.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect PRAM has some bad contents.
Check this article on how to reset PRAM:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Additionally, you may need to reset SMC:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I have solved this problem. Just turn off the FileVault !

Comment: That seems like a high price to pay to resolve the issue. Loosing disk encryption may have drawbacks.